# Hidden Form Element Password Safety

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form that has to pass data across two pages.

On page 1 the user fills in a few details. Page 2 presents them with a confirmation screen where they can either agree or go back and edit their details.

On page 2 the values from page 1 are stored in hidden form fields.

E.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_email" value="email@test.com" />
```

When the user hits submit on page 2 some PHP code runs and they're added to the site.

On page 1 the user enters a password and my concern is how I handle this on page 2. I don't think outputting it in the hidden form field is a good idea. The PHP that runs will hash this password anyway so I was thinking of hashing it between page 1 and page 2 so that the hidden form field's value is the hashed version instead of plain text. Is there an even better way I could be doing this?

Comment: As long as you are using POST data and not appending anything to the URL on page 2 then just put the plain-text password into the hidden field. I would strongly advise against putting the hashed password into the hidden field because you are just begging to get reverse-engineered.

Comment: Why you think outputting password in the hidden form field is not a good idea? No one but the user can read its value

Comment: @hindmost Browser addons, for one example, can read it. Or copy paste into rich text format like an email. It just doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Comment: @hindmost I read in another thread about disk based caching potentially resulting in the pws being stored on the server in plain text form as well as other issues leading to the same outcome.

Comment: @Wesley Murch In this case browser addon should know all about OP's site, including where to look for such hidden field. Imho too complex scenario.

Comment: @hindmost It's really not complex at all, but of course you'd want to target a popular website. It's just one example, and to me one is more than enough.

Comment: @Nathan Dawson I didn't suggested you to store password on the server in plain text. This is exactly a bad idea. But I don't mind passing unhashed password through several pages while POST method is used for passing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use session variables to store this information, never pass it back to the page as hidden form fields. `$_SESSION`

Comment: I like this approach. I've set the session variable to the hashed PW. The function for hashing the PW is part of a well known open source application so I'm not too worried about it being reverse engineered. What is the best function to sanitize the value before attempting to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Input the data inserted in page 1 into a database table (called `pending_user_register` or something) that has a unique hash (don't just use the unique ID) and then reference the unique hash in the hidden text field instead?

Or go the simple route and use $_SESSION.

Or, use the above method but instead of a hidden field put it in the $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `password_hash()` and can store the password in `session` or `cookie`

**OR** can store the `user data` in database and add `user_id` in `session` and use that `id` for later `updation of fields`.